# Best way to set cookies in a Django view?

Tags: python, django

I'm working on modifying a Django view that is similar to the following:

```
class ListBase(DashboardAccessMixin, OrderingMixin, FilterMixin, SearchMixin):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if should_delete_filter_cookie(request, path=reverse('dashboard:families')):
            request.COOKIES.pop('filters', None)

        self.query_dict = query_dict_from_params_or_cookies(request)

        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def render_to_response(self, context, **response_kwargs):
        response = super().render_to_response(context, **response_kwargs)

        path = reverse('dashboard:families')

        if should_delete_filter_cookie(self.request, path=path):
            response.delete_cookie('filters', path=path)
        elif list(self.request.GET.items()):
            response.set_cookie('filters', self.request.GET.urlencode(), path=path)

        return response
```

where the auxiliary functions `should_delete_filter_cookie` and `query_dict_from_params_or_cookies` are defined as

```
def query_dict_from_params_or_cookies(request):
    query_dict = request.GET

    cookie_filters = request.COOKIES.get('filters')

    if cookie_filters and not list(query_dict.items()):
        query_dict = QueryDict(cookie_filters)

    return query_dict


def should_delete_filter_cookie(request, path):
    referer_path = urlparse(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')).path

    if referer_path and path not in referer_path:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

The view has a `filter_form` and a `search_form` (through the corresponding mixins) which are bound with `self.query_dict`. Further, we follow the naming convention that the URLs for the `UpdateView` and `CreateView` are simply 'extensions' of that for the `ListView`'s URL: for example, the former is `/dashboard/families` and the latter is simply `dashboard/families/1` (but not `dashboard/family/1`).

The `ListView` is now such that when you return to it from an `UpdateView`, it persists the filters that were previously applied by getting the `self.query_dict` from the cookies.

What I'm wondering is why `should_delete_filter_cookie` is invoked twice, in the `get()` method and in the `render_to_response()` method. Should it not suffice to do this just once?

Also, why is `response.set_cookie` used in the `render_to_response` method rather than just `request.COOKIES['filters'] = request.GET.urlencode()` in the `get()` method?

On a more fundamental level, I'm struggling to understand what the difference is between `request.COOKIES` and `response.cookies`. For example, in the following test case,

```
from django.test import SimpleTestCase, RequestFactory
from django.urls import reverse
from http.cookies import SimpleCookie


class SearchFilterTest(SimpleTestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # Use a RequestFactory instead of a Client to obtain Request objects instead of Response objects
        self.factory = RequestFactory()

    def test_get_with_cookies(self):
        self.client.cookies = SimpleCookie({'filters': 'q=Christine'})
        response = self.client.get(
            reverse('dashboard:families'),
            HTTP_REFERER=reverse('dashboard:family', kwargs={'pk': 1, 'tab': 'case-management'}))
        import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
```

If I drop into the debugger I see that `response.cookies` is an empty `SimpleCookie`, even though a cookie has been set for the test client:

```
ipdb> response.cookies
<SimpleCookie: >
```

Does `response.cookies` represent only the cookies that are set with `response.set_cookie`, and not the ones that came with the original request?

Also, what is the best way to set cookies in this use case, in the `get()` or `render_to_response()` method?